# Draw an area on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to hang the drawing line with the cursor while drawing. i tried with mousemove event but did not got it working. Below is what i'm having at the moment.

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qwd2a/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var canvasMouseX;
        var canvasMouseY;
        var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
        var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
        var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
        var storedLines = [];

        ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
        ctx.font = '12px Arial';

        $("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
            handleMouseDown(e);
        });

        function handleMouseDown(e) {
            canvasMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            canvasMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

            // Put your mousedown stuff here
            storedLines.push({
                x: canvasMouseX,
                y: canvasMouseY
            });
            var count = storedLines.length;
            var X = canvasMouseX - (count < 10 ? 4 : 7);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(canvasMouseX, canvasMouseY, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fillText(storedLines.length, X, canvasMouseY + 4);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        $("#draw").click(function () {
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(storedLines[0].x, storedLines[0].y);
            for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
                ctx.lineTo(storedLines[i].x, storedLines[i].y);
            }
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            storedLines = [];
        });

        $("#clear").click(function () {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            storedLines = [];
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a canvas you are responsible for redrawing the entire contents everytime it is needed. This means that when the mouse cursor moves, you need to clear the canvas and then redraw all of the current line segments. Based on your code I have come up with the following sample for how it can be done:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click to draw lines</p>
<p>Click back in the green circle to close+fill</p>
<br/>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<br/>
<button id="clear">Clear Canvas</button>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            offset = $("#canvas").offset(),
            storedLines = [],
            polyLines = [],
            start = {x: 0, y: 0},
            radius = 7;

        function canvasPosition(e) {
            return {
                x: parseInt(e.clientX - offset.left),
                y: parseInt(e.clientY - offset.top)
            };
        }

        $("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
            var pos = canvasPosition(e);
            if (hitStartCircle(pos)) {
                polyLines.push(storedLines);
                storedLines = [];
                draw();
            }
            else
            {
                storedLines.push(pos);
                update(pos);
            }
        })
        .mousemove(function (e) {
            update(canvasPosition(e));
        });

        // Draw completed polylines
        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            $.each(polyLines, function (idx, polyLine) {
                fillPolyline(polyLine);
            });
        }

        // Update shape currently being drawn
        function update(position) {
            var len = storedLines.length;
            if(len==0) return;

            draw();
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(storedLines[0].x, storedLines[0].y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(storedLines[0].x, storedLines[0].y);
            for(var i=1; i<len; ++i) {
                ctx.lineTo(storedLines[i].x, storedLines[i].y)
            }
            ctx.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
            ctx.stroke();
        };

        function hitStartCircle(pos) {
            var start = storedLines[0] || {x:0, y:0},
                dx = pos.x - start.x,
                dy = pos.y - start.y;
            return (dx * dx + dy * dy < radius * radius)
        }

        function fillPolyline(lines) {
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(lines[0].x, lines[0].y);
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                ctx.lineTo(lines[i].x, lines[i].y);
            }
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        $("#clear").click(function () {
            polyLines = [];
            draw();
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will correctly update the last segment as the user moves the mouse cursor.

Comment: hi! thanks for the solution.Is there any thing i could try to remember the filled polygon after it has been completed?

Comment: @TAS: Your solution is great! There is some simplest way to edit drawn shape (move one of coordinates)?

Comment: @kicaj No, you need to redraw the entire canvas.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your jsfiddle, there is an offset when drawing a new line.
This is occurring because of the the padding in body in your css.

Just replace this:

```
body {
    background-color: ivory;
    padding:10px;
}
```

with this:

```
body {
    background-color: ivory;
}
```